# Ext$^1(D(A),A)$ for hereditary algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a hereditary (non-semisimple) finite-dimensional algebra over a field $K$. Let $M:={\rm Ext}^{1}_A(D(A),A)$ ($ \cong D(\tau((D(A)))$ as left modules) and let $A^e$ be the enveloping algebra (with module category isomorphic to the category of A-bimodules).

Viewed as a right $A^e$-module, what is the decomposition of $M$ (in terms of indecomposables)?

What is ${\rm End}_{A^e}(M)$?

One can also replace *hereditary* by *global dimension equalling $n$* and $M$ by ${\rm Ext}^n(D(A),A)$ in these questions.